# Hudson SVN Checkout failures occur frequenctly on VMWare virtual machines

Tags: svn, hudson, virtual-machine

We've recently been experiencing seemingly random SVN checkout failures on our Hudson build system. Google search has failed me; I'm hoping the stackoverflow community can help me out :-)

We are occasionally receiving the following SVN error when our Hudson build jobs checkout source via the Hudson Subversion plug-in (which uses svn kit):

> ERROR: Failed to check out `http://server/svnroot/project/projectTrunk` org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: Processing REPORT request response failed: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity. (/svnroot/!svn/vcc/default) svn: REPORT request failed on '/svnroot/!svn/vcc/default'

This issue seems to only occur when checking out from our Virtual Machines (Windows XP, Fedora 9, Fedora 12) using Hudson's SVN Plug-in. Systems that use the traditional SVN client seem to work.

SVN Server version: 1.6.6
Hudson version: 1.377
Hudson SVN Plugin Version: 1.17

Has anyone dealt with this issue, or have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I read recently, that this can happen. when the app checks out too much at once. Usually several MB. The simplified cause is, that when the svn client downloads from SVN it will immediately try to process the results. If too much data is requested, the message buffer will overflow and packets will be dropped, which results in non conforming xml.

This issue seems to be linked to svn kit. I am not sure, if the developer using the framework can implement strategies against this effect.

In your case I would check the health of my VM server. Does the Hudson VM gets enough resources? The fact, that it is happening just recently (assuming that Hudson already runs for a while on the VM), I would check into VM and network.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue, though it was old thread, i would like to provide solution for this.

Atleast in my case.

`ERROR: Failed to check out http://server/svnroot/project/projectTrunk org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: Processing REPORT request response failed: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity. (/svnroot/!svn/vcc/default) svn: REPORT request failed on '/svnroot/!svn/vcc/default'`

Along with that i had console output saying 
`Caused by: ........... path/to/file/.svn/tmp permision denied.`

we occasionally overlook but it was not owned by jenkins and was hidden file.
chown file to jenkins it should solve it.